# SQL Insert statement with two values, where one of them is from a SELECT result

Tags: sql, select, insert

I am trying to make an insertstatement with one of the values comming from a select statement.

```
INSERT INTO Politi.Sager_Kontonumre VALUES (@sagsID, <Result from Select>);
```

The select statement:

```
SELECT k.id FROM Bank.Kontonumre k WHERE k.registreringsnummer = @registreringsnummer AND k.kontonummer = @kontonummer;
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into below query as well. It helps when multiple select statements you have.

```
INSERT INTO Politi.Sager_Kontonumre
SELECT @sagsID, (SELECT k.id FROM Bank.Kontonumre k WHERE k.registreringsnummer = @registreringsnummer AND k.kontonummer = @kontonummer)
```

Comment: INSERT INTO Politi.Sager_Kontonumre VALUES (@sagsID, (SELECT k.id FROM Bank.Kontonumre k WHERE k.registreringsnummer = @registreringsnummer AND k.kontonummer = @kontonummer));

Answer (score 2):

Simply do an *INSERT with SELECT*:

```
INSERT INTO Politi.Sager_Kontonumre
  SELECT @sagsID, k.id
  FROM Bank.Kontonumre k
  WHERE k.registreringsnummer = @registreringsnummer AND k.kontonummer = @kontonummer;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
INSERT INTO Politi.Sager_Kontonumre
    SELECT @sagsID, k.id 
     FROM Bank.Kontonumre k
     WHERE k.registreringsnummer = @registreringsnummer 
       AND k.kontonummer = @Kontonummer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `SELECT` value that you wish to insert into an sql variable that you later use in your `INSERT` satement.

Example:

```
SET @sensibleVariableName = (SELECT
                               k.id
                             FROM
                               Bank.Kontonumre k
                             WHERE
                               k.registreringsnummer = @registreringsnummer
                             AND
                               k.kontonummer = @kontonummer);

INSERT INTO Politi.Sager_Kontonumre VALUES (@sagsID, @sensibleVariableName);
```